# Partition lists of integers based on unique sets of numbers they contain

Tags: c#, linq, merge, duplicates, set-theory

I have a list of integer list like -

```
List<List<int>> dataList = new List<List<int>> {
                new List<int>{ 0, 2, 4, 7 },
                new List<int>{ 1, 6, 3 },
                new List<int>{ 2, 0, 7, 9 },
                new List<int>{ 3, 1, 6 },
                new List<int>{ 4, 0, 2 },
                new List<int>{ 5, 2, 7 },
            };
```

I want to merge all the list those have duplicates and generate a list of integer list where no values should be common in any list.

The output should be like--

0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9

1, 3, 6

Comment: What happens if an (additional) input is: `{ 1, 2 }`? Is there then a single output or..?

Comment: @user2864740 then output will be only one list with 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, then it will be only single output that should be like List<List<int> output={ {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9} };

Comment: Naively, I'd start with each number being it's own "set", eg. `{1=> {1}, 2=>{2}}`. When a number if found in the same sequence as another number then it's also added to that set, and collapsed to the same instance (ie. take set object instance of smaller number): `{1=> {1,2}, 2=> /* same instance as 1 */}`, eg.. after all the sequences are processed this way, there will be `{1=>..,n=>..}` where the *values* will be distinct sets. I'm sure there is way more awesome approach.

Comment: @user2864740 I can solve this in your way but that needs to do looping through each element of each list. I was expecting how can I do that using Linq.

Comment: @emdad, you have clear input and expected output values, write tests, write ugliest possible solution with loops, which makes tests pass. Update question with ugliest solution if you will not be able to refactor it within LINQ ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want one single list, then you can do this:

```
// flatten your list:
var newList = new List<int>();
foreach (var list in output) {
  newList.AddRange(list);
}
// make sure every number is only once in that list:
newList.Distinct() // here is linq!
var output = new List<List<int>>();
output.Add(newList);
```